# Asp.net 5 mvc 6 get query string to view

Tags: query-string, asp.net-core-mvc

I have been googling for a few hours. But still not able to get the answer.  I need to get a query string parameter in a razor view.

Here is my code:

```
              if @(Request.Query["value"]=="P"){

                    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Staff",new { status = "A"})"><strong>Active (@ViewData["activeCount"]) </strong></a> &nbsp;
                    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Staff",new { status = "I" })">In-Active (@ViewData["inActiveCount"])</a>&nbsp;
                    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Staff",new { status = "D" })">Delete (@ViewData["deleteCount"])</a>&nbsp;
               }else{
                    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Staff",new { status = "A"})">Active (@ViewData["activeCount"])</a> &nbsp;
                    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Staff",new { status = "I" })"><strong>In-Active (@ViewData["inActiveCount"])<strong></a>&nbsp;
                    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Staff",new { status = "D" })">Delete (@ViewData["deleteCount"])</a>&nbsp;

               }
```

But i get the error "**The name 'Request' does not exist in the current context**"

The screenshot
[image]
Anyone got solution? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using Context.Request.Query ["value"] rather than just Request.Query ["value"]?

Comment: yes.thanks your answer

Comment: Sure thing, I'm glad it worked for you

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Use `Context.Request.Query["value"]`  rather than `Request.Query["value"]`

Comment: Surprised how long it took to find this answer

Answer (score 1):

Yes you finally can. The answer is `Context.Request.Query ["value"]`